springdoc integration not working as expected for springboot
I am following this to integrate springdoc in my springboot application.
Springboot version is 3.3.1 and I have added dependency:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

Dependency tree:
[INFO] +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-common:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core-jakarta:jar:2.2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations-jakarta:jar:2.2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models-jakarta:jar:2.2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:5.13.0:compile

But for me none of the links work:
http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Both has 'This site can’t be reached' message on browser.
Do I need any extra configuration?

I always define the paths explicitly:
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /public/v3/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /public/swagger-ui.html

and then they will be available under localhost:8080/public/swagger-ui/index.html

Keep in mind that if you have defined the property context-path:
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /foo-service

then it will be part of the url: localhost:8080/foo-service/public/swagger-ui/index.html

Lastly make sure you are not getting 403 because of spring security (open the network tab to see the error codes)

My application is running on port 8089. Does it impact api-docs and swagger?

just the localhost part, e.g. localhost:8089/public/swagger-ui/index.html
